# Select distinct values ignoring one field

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to this

```
Table(Id int, PropertyId int, UserId int, AccesedOn datetime)
```

So the table can have value for one property for one user, but different times.

```
Eg.
1,100,5, 2012-10-16 16:24:48
2,100,5, 2012-10-17 11:22:00
3,100,5, 2012-10-18 17:10:05
```

What I am trying here is to select distinct properties for specific user, but order by most recent access time.

Also I am joining this table to three other tables which result in providing duplicate values. Therefore I have to use `DISTINCT` command.

Problem I have is since I doing the `orderby AccesedOn`, it need to appear on select statement which doesn’t brings the distinct values since the ***AccesedOn*** column have different values.

For above example it should return only `3,100,5, 2012-10-18 17:10:05`

Any suggestions to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE as(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PropertyId,UserId  order by AccesedOn desc) as rn
from table1)

select * from CTE where rn=1
```

Comment: This seems like SQL Server's weirded-out way of achieving this, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely that you need a subselect than that you need a distinct for this.

```
select * 
from Table A
where AccessedOn in
  (Select max(AccessedOn) from table B where A.UserId = B.UserId)
```

Comment: This will result in selecting only one record

Comment: I think it will give one record for every UsedId, in this example there is only one UserID, so yes in this example the outcome is one record. Wasn't that the question? Have you tried it on larger tables?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `DISTINCT`, you can use `MAX()` and group by the rest of the columns

```
Select Id, PropertyId, UserId, MAX(AccesedOn)
From Table t
group by Id, PropertyId, UserId
```

This should give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: Your query does not give the result huMpty duMpty is after. Grouping using the `Id` field will return ALL rows. SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb4d1/1

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this, the Id column should be removed from the select and the group by.

Comment: Then you would not return the result the OP asked for, he wants the `Id` field in the result, e.g.: `3,100,5, 2012-10-18 17:10:05`